# Can I pass api response from a django views without using django-rest framework

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to pass values from django views to a react front end.I have not worked with django rest framework.I want to know if I can pass values from views in django to a react app, if so how?What should the views function return which can be given to the react app?

Answer (score 2):

*React* usually calls a web *API* using it's URL to get data in **JSON** format from server. It does this using `fetch` (*Promise*) or clients like [**axios**](https://github.com/axios/axios) usually.

**Django REST Framework** helps you to create *RESTfull Web API* much easier; but you can do it manually using *Django* too.

You can return `JsonResponse` object instead of `HttpResponse` from your *views*. You can get more information on [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects).

Here's an example.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def my_views(request):
    data = {
        'message': 'Hello World!',
        'status': 'OK'
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Finally based on the response which returned from the *API* (e.g. using `status_code`), client gives suitable feedback to user.

Comment: after returning the JsonResponse how should I check if it's working or not and how to use it in the react app?

Comment: @AhmadJaved I've added to the answer. Let's check it!